# Softwares to reduce bass in speakers

Tags: audio, windows-10

I use JBL speakers and connect them to my laptop (Windows 10). For songs it's good.

But sometimes during meetings, it is not good. It's all verbal and the speakers naturally have high bass.

Is there any software which can toggle the bass or sound coming out of speakers (kind of verbal mode / song mode)?  (Or some setting in Windows 10?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes there are such settings built-in with your sound device, however, not all of them have it. If so, it's called "Low frequency protection" and it has a setting for the frequency.

In the Windows 10 settings (new settings, not old control panel), you find it like this:

- Sound
- Under "Output", click "Device properties"
- Under "Related settings", click "Additional device properties"
- In the window that opens, go to the tab "Enhancements"
- Check "Low frequency protection"
- Click "Settings"
- Choose a frequency that you think will help. The higher you set it, the more low frequencies will be cut off.

[image: Low frequency protection]

There might also be other options to eliminate bass (which is low frequencies). A bass boost might work as well, if it's possible to apply a negative bass boost. Also, if you find an equalizer, you can reduce the low frequencies.

[image: Frequency curves]

Comment: I wanted to post a pic here. But couldnt dont know how to. If i go to enhancements it doesnt show low frequency protection.  I see Bass Boost, virtual sound,...all unchecked by default.  If i click on settings button it does show frequency and boost level the HZ and db. Is Bass a low frequency sound kind of like having a low Hz ?? Does db matter ??

Comment: As side question - you posted an embedded pic. Generally when i upload an image it comes as a link. how did you do that ? Thanks

Comment: Regarding the image, I typically have the image in the clipboard, because I just created a screenshot. Then I simply press Ctrl+V. This uploads the image and inserts it. This only works in questions and answers, not in comments.

Comment: Bass boost might work. The dB values matter. +6dB is double volume. +12dB ist 4x volume. +18dB is 8x volume. If you can set this to a negative value, like -6dB it will be half the volume. Since it is called "Bass boost", it should only affect the bass, not the rest.

Comment: If you think in terms of Hz if you are moving out of low Hz zones then bass will automatically be lower ?

Comment: Yes, bass is equal to low frequencies. If you find a setting called "equalizer", that might work as well. I've added some more graphics.